# Hibernate: what's the difference between MySQLDialect and MySQLInnoDBDialect?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

What's the difference between MySQLDialect and MySQLInnoDBDialect? I've used MySQLDialect ever since, now I wonder how the above are different.

Anyone?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default storage engine in MySQL is [`MyISAM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html). If you need transactions and row-level locking, you often chose [`InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-storage-engine.html).

Using `MySQLInnoDBDialect`, Hibernate appends `type=InnoDB` to the table creation statement. This explicitly creates an `InnoDB` table. `MySQLDialect` does not append an engine string, thus, would create a `MyISAM` table.

However, you can also change the default storage engine of the MySQL server by using the following line in your `my.cnf`, MySQL configuration, file.

```
default-storage-engine=innodb
```

Comment: Okay the DDL ENGINE = InnoDB makes sense, but is that all?

Comment: Almost. This class also turns on DB-side cascade on delete. Look at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLInnoDBDialect.java.html).