# JPA @ManyToOne Saving Issue

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I have two entity called 'Group' and 'Generic'. When I tried to save Generic data in mySql with the reference of Group it save a new record to group table then use this record in Generic table. How to fix this problem???

Group Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mdcn_group")
public class Group extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
protected Long id;

private String name;
private int status;
private String comments;

public Group() {
}

public Group(long id){
    this.id = id;
}

public Group(long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
// ... getter and setter
```

Generic Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "generic")
public class Generic extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
protected Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
private Group group;
private String name;
private int status;
private String comments;

public Generic(){}

public Generic(long id){
    this.id = id;
}

public Generic(long id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
// ... getter and setter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its your dialect configuration not match with your database. I get this problem sometimes ago.

Go to your ***application.properties or config file*** change hibernate dialect "MySQL5Dialect" to "MySQL5InnoDBDialect".

```
#hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: Could you please explain why `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` did not work?

Comment: I didn't find why `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` not worked. Probably that problem for the engine. 

The default storage engine in MySQL is MyISAM. If you need transactions and row-level locking, you often chose InnoDB.
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368195/hibernate-whats-the-difference-between-mysqldialect-and-mysqlinnodbdialect)

Comment: I'm using mariadb for my rdbms. mariadb suggest to use 'MySQL5InnoDBDialect'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the Generic entity mapped in your Group entity. Please refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)

Please add below mapping in Group entity class and try.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group")
private List<Generic> generic;
```

Comment: I couldn't deduce anything from "doesn't work" comment. Please provide more details like error, stacktrace, code, etc.

Comment: It behave like earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your cascade. Please remove the cascade from your Generic object.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
private Group group;
```